# Proto + Kafka Producer: Error serializing object to JSON: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain unknownFields

Tags: apache-kafka, grpc, micronaut, proto, micronaut-kafka

Stack: Micronaut-Kafka, Proto3, gRPC, BloomRPC

Goal: reiceve a grpc request from BloomRPC and post it to a kafka topic

Context: I coded a gRPC endpoint which receives a simple call successfully but when trying to post such object to Kafka topic I get

```
12:38:18.775 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] ERROR i.m.r.intercept.RecoveryInterceptor - Type [com.mybank.producer.DebitProducer$Intercepted] executed with error: Exception sending producer record for method [void sendRequestMessage(String key,DebitRequest message)]: Error serializing object to JSON: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: com.mybank.endpoint.DebitRequest["unknownFields"]->com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet["defaultInstanceForType"])
io.micronaut.messaging.exceptions.MessagingClientException: Exception sending producer record for method [void sendRequestMessage(String key,DebitRequest message)]: Error serializing object to JSON: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: com.mybank.endpoint.DebitRequest["unknownFields"]->com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet["defaultInstanceForType"])
    at io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.intercept.KafkaClientIntroductionAdvice.wrapException(KafkaClientIntroductionAdvice.java:564)
```

I guess somehow my issue is related to "...Error serializing object to JSON". Do I really have to convert such object to json? Can I not just post it to kafka topic? What  I am missing here? Well, I can easily fix this issue by creating a new object and setting each property to it accordingly to the request object like this:

endpoint (controller) method

```
override suspend fun sendDebit(request: DebitRequest): DebitReply {

    var dtoDebiter: Debiter = Debiter() 
    dtoDebiter.id = request.id.toString()
    dtoDebiter.name = request.name

    transactionService.postDebitTransaction(dtoDebiter)
    return DebitReply.newBuilder().setMessage(postStatus).build()
}
```

Model created only for conversion (doesn't seem weird this solution???)

```
class Debiter {
    lateinit var id: String
    lateinit var name: String
}
```

So, my straight question is: can I reuse the same autogenerated stub resulted from the proto file as a model both for receiving the request and posting it to kafka topic? If so, what is wrong in code bellow? If not, what is the recommended approach?

Full code:

transaction.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "com.mybank.endpoint";
option java_outer_classname = "TransactionProto";
option objc_class_prefix = "HLW";

package com.mybank.endpoint;

service Account {
  rpc SendDebit (DebitRequest) returns (DebitReply) {}
}

message DebitRequest {
  int64 id = 1;
  string name = 2;
}

message DebitReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

transaction endpoint (controller)

```
package com.mybank.endpoint

import com.mybank.dto.Debiter
import com.mybank.service.TransactionService
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
@Suppress("unused")
class TransactionEndpoint(val transactionService: TransactionService) : AccountGrpcKt.AccountCoroutineImplBase(){

    override suspend fun sendDebit(request: DebitRequest): DebitReply {

        var postStatus: String = transactionService.postDebitTransaction(request)
        return DebitReply.newBuilder().setMessage(postStatus).build()
    }

}
```

transaction service (not really relevant here)

```
package com.mybank.service

import com.mybank.dto.Debiter
import com.mybank.dto.Transaction
import com.mybank.dto.Transactions
import com.mybank.endpoint.DebitRequest
import com.mybank.producer.DebitProducer
import javax.inject.Inject
import javax.inject.Named
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
class TransactionService(){

    @Inject
    @Named("debitProducer")
    lateinit var debitProducer : DebitProducer

    fun postDebitTransaction(debit: DebitRequest) : String{

        debitProducer.sendRequestMessage ("1", debit)

        return "posted"
    }
}
```

kafka producer

```
package com.mybank.producer

import com.mybank.dto.Transaction
import com.mybank.dto.Transactions
import com.mybank.endpoint.DebitRequest
import io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.annotation.KafkaClient
import io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.annotation.KafkaKey
import io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.annotation.Topic

@KafkaClient
public interface DebitProducer {

    @Topic("debit")
    fun sendRequestMessage(@KafkaKey key: String?, message: DebitRequest?) {
    }

}
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.3.72"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt" version "1.3.72"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen" version "1.3.72"
    id "application"
    id 'com.google.protobuf' version '0.8.13'
}

version "0.2"
group "account-control"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
}

configurations {
    // for dependencies that are needed for development only
    developmentOnly
}

dependencies {
    kapt(enforcedPlatform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion"))
    kapt("io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java")
    kapt("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")

    implementation(enforcedPlatform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion"))
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlinxCoroutinesVersion")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
//    implementation("io.micronaut.grpc:micronaut-grpc-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut.grpc:micronaut-grpc-server-runtime:$micronautGrpcVersion")
    implementation("io.micronaut.grpc:micronaut-grpc-client-runtime:$micronautGrpcVersion")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-kotlin-stub:${grpcKotlinVersion}")

    //Kafka
    implementation("io.micronaut.kafka:micronaut-kafka")

    //vertx
    implementation("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-vertx-mysql-client")
    //implementation("io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-vertx-mysql-client")
    compile 'io.vertx:vertx-lang-kotlin:3.9.4'

    //mongodb
    implementation("org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-reactivestreams:4.1.1")

    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3")
    runtimeOnly("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.8")

    kaptTest("io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java")

    testImplementation enforcedPlatform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.0")
    testImplementation("io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-junit5")
    testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:2.22.0")

    testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.0")
    testRuntime("org.jetbrains.spek:spek-junit-platform-engine:1.1.5")
}

test.classpath += configurations.developmentOnly

mainClassName = "account-control.Application"

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

allOpen {
    annotation("io.micronaut.aop.Around")
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11' 
        //Will retain parameter names for Java reflection
        javaParameters = true 
    }
}
//compileKotlin.dependsOn(generateProto)

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11' 
        javaParameters = true 
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    classpath += configurations.developmentOnly
    jvmArgs('-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1', '-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote')
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc'
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/grpckt'
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/java'
        }
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc { artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:${protocVersion}" }
    plugins {
        grpc { artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpcVersion}" }
        grpckt { artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:${grpcKotlinVersion}" }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins {
            grpc {}
            grpckt {}
        }
    }
}
```

in case it is relevant, here is a piece of the stub autogenerated by proto

```
    // Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
    // source: transaction.proto
    
    package com.mybank.endpoint;
    
    /**
     * Protobuf type {@code com.mybank.endpoint.DebitRequest}
     */
    public final class DebitRequest extends
        com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3 implements
        // @@protoc_insertion_point(message_implements:com.mybank.endpoint.DebitRequest)
        DebitRequestOrBuilder {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;
      // Use DebitRequest.newBuilder() to construct.
      private DebitRequest(com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3.Builder<?> builder) {
        super(builder);
      }
      private DebitRequest() {
        name_ = "";
      }
    
      @java.lang.Override
      @SuppressWarnings({"unused"})
      protected java.lang.Object newInstance(
          UnusedPrivateParameter unused) {
        return new DebitRequest();
      }
    
      @java.lang.Override
      public final com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet
      getUnknownFields() {
        return this.unknownFields;
      }
      private DebitRequest(
          com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream input,
          com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
          throws com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException {
        this();
...
```

*** First edition

```
@KafkaClient(
        id="debit-client",
        acks = KafkaClient.Acknowledge.ALL,
        properties = [Property(name = ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, value = "5")]
        //How add these two properties in order to use Protobuf Serializer
        //kafka.producers.*.key-serializer
        //kafka.producers.*.value-serializer
)
public interface DebitProducer {

    @Topic("debit")
    fun sendRequestMessage(@KafkaKey key: String?, message: DebitRequest?) {
    }
```

*** Second Edition

I tried added the serializer via application.yaml

```
micronaut:
    application:
        name: account-control
grpc:
    server:
        port: 8082
kafka:
    producers:
        product-client:
            value:
                serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.protobuf.KafkaProtobufSerializer
```

gradle.build

```
//kafka-protobuf-serializer
    implementation("io.confluent:kafka-protobuf-serializer:6.0.0")
```

and now I get during gradle build

```
Execution failed for task ':extractIncludeProto'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileProtoPath'.
   > Could not resolve com.squareup.wire:wire-schema:3.2.2.
     Required by:
         project : > io.confluent:kafka-protobuf-serializer:6.0.0 > io.confluent:kafka-protobuf-provider:6.0.0
      > The consumer was configured to find a component, preferably only the resources files. However we cannot choose between the following variants of com.squareup.wire:wire-schema:3.2.2:
          - jvm-api
          - jvm-runtime
          - metadata-api
        All of them match the consumer attributes:
          - Variant 'jvm-api' capability com.squareup.wire:wire-schema:3.2.2 declares a component, packaged as a jar:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides an API but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'jvm-runtime' capability com.squareup.wire:wire-schema:3.2.2 declares a component, packaged as a jar:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides a runtime but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'metadata-api' capability com.squareup.wire:wire-schema:3.2.2:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them preferably only the resources files)
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides a usage of 'kotlin-api' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'common' but the consumer didn't ask for it

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':extractIncludeProto'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:370)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:357)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:350)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileProtoPath'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:1265)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1800(DefaultConfiguration.java:141)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.visitContents(DefaultConfiguration.java:1242)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.visitContents(DefaultConfiguration.java:1235)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.visitContents(DefaultConfiguration.java:489)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:265)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitContents(CompositeFileCollection.java:152)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:265)
    at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.impl.DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.impl.AbstractFileCollectionFingerprinter.fingerprint(AbstractFileCollectionFingerprinter.java:47)
    at ...

ultPlanExecutor.java:182)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
```

Comment: do you want to post the whole message or just the DebitRequest? cause it seems that the GeneratedMessageV3  has some self-reference which cannot handled by default. So eigther - if that is possible - use some Jackson-Ignore properties on the specific field, or create an own jackson serializer, if the class cannot be changed or - what i prefer - create some kind of "DTO" for sending the data you want (and only that) to the kafka topic .. kafka is no object store, therefore you must serialize it and default is json

Comment: @IEE1394, thanks. I am in learning curve and both scenario may happen: the whole message or just DebitRequest. Above I am trying just Debitrequest. The solution a added is exactly this: I created a DTO class Debiter and add each property to it. This works. But it seems so weird. See this article https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-protobuf-with-apache-kafka-and-schema-r where the protobuf object is been sent straight to Kafka. I ran successfully the example but I couldn't figure out yet what I have to do in order to post to kafka topic the DebitRequest received without transformation

Comment: yeah in the article you mentioned they use a KafkaProtobufSerializer default its some kind of json serializer

Comment: see here how to configure that in micronaut https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-kafka/latest/guide/configurationreference.html

Comment: or specify the property directly in the @KafkaListener https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-kafka/latest/guide/#kafkaListener

Comment: @IEE1394, regard your first link, how can I add kafka.producers.*.key-serializer 
 and kafka.producers.*.value-serializer in KafkaClient (producer)? I added above my KafkaClient.

Comment: @IEE1394 according to your second link, "You can, however, explicitly override the Serializer.. You may want to do this if for example you choose an alternative serialization format such as Avro or Protobuf". I guess I need to override the Serializer providing Protobuf. Any clue how reach that?

Comment: I  am getting could not resolve com.squareup.wire:wire-schema:3.2.2. Does it mean something to you?

Comment: try adding  mavenCentral() to your repositories